# SharePoint - Using Powershell to get site information

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, powershell

I am trying to get the following information from all my sites.

Site Name, Site URL, Users with Full Control(in groups or not), User Email

I am able to get the Site Name and Site URL with Powershell. Anybody know how to also get users with full control and their email? (I tried but couldn't get users that were in groups along with those who weren't and it was a separate script, want them combined in one excel doc.). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this powershell script  Site Name, Site URL, Users with Full Control(in groups or not), User Email

```
  $Url="http://sp"
  $web= Get-SPWeb $Url

    Write-Host $web.Title $web.Url-ForegroundColor red
    $roles=$web.get_Roles()
    Foreach($role in $roles)
    {
    if( $role.Name  -eq "Full Control"){
        Write-Host "permission level" $role.Name -ForegroundColor green
        Write-Host "group has this permission:"
        $groups=$role.Groups
        if($groups.Count -eq 0){
            Write-Host "no group has this permissoon" -ForegroundColor red
        }else{
            Foreach($group in $groups)
            {
             Write-Host $group
             $groupUsers=$group.Users
             if($groupUsers.Count -eq 0){
                Write-Host "this group does not has users"
             }else{
                Foreach($groupUser in $groupUsers){
                
                Write-Host "User:" $groupUser "Email:"$groupUser.Email
                }
             }
            }
        
        }    
        Write-Host "-------------"
        Write-Host "user has this permission:"
        
        $users = $role.Users 
        if($users.Count -eq 0){
            Write-Host "no user has this permissoon directly" -ForegroundColor red
        }else{
            Foreach($user in $users)
            {
             Write-Host "User:" $user "Email:"$user.Email
            }
        }
        }
    }
```

Test result:
[image]

Comment: Hi Amos, Thanks for your reply. I need all of this in a spreadsheet. Is there anyway to get Site, SiteURL, User, UserEmail, Role Name all in one line?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21047185/how-to-export-data-to-csv-in-powershell
You could refer to this issue to export data to csv, Some data has many values, I think the experience will not be very good.